# Managing Application Access with OpenID Connect and OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identity, openid-connect

Looking through the OpenID Connect and OAuth specs, it seems that OpenID connect is all about identity and OAuth is about delegated access (though it seems to be specifically **API** access).

If OAuth is meant for API access, what is the recommended approach for managing **client** access? OpenID Connect can say who you are, but what says which clients (applications) you can access.

Is this the job of the application itself or something that we can put onto an access token?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to know, so I'll try to answer it more broadly.

Let's say you have one authentication (OAuth2) provider, multiple applications (clients) using it and multiple users.

If a client gets an ID token, the token is supposed to be used just for verifying user identity by the client who requested it - ID tokens contain the `aud` (audience) field with the client's `client_id`.

If a client gets an access token authorized by a resource owner, the client can use the access token to access any resource (API service) that accepts tokens issued by the authorization provider. But the API service checks whether the access token contains scopes required by the service. If the client requests a scope that the resource owner cannot delegate (not enough rights), the authentication provider can [return error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) `invalid_scope` or just omit the scope from the access token. The decision whether the client can delegate the scope is up to the auth provider implementation (the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) doesn't cover it).

If you want to restrict some user / client combinations, so the user cannot authorize the client to get a token, then again, it's an implementation detail of your authentication provider.

If your question is more about what the authenticated user is allowed to do in an application which has its ID token (or access token), then it's up to you to decide how to do it. Applications usually need to restrict access to services and data. The services are generally static and the access could be based on access token scopes. But the application data is dynamic and the access is usually based on the data ownership or access control lists (ACLs - like on file systems).

Comment: To be more explicit, I'm talking about Client access. An API is not involved at all. A user navigates to a Client, the Client redirects them to the token service, and then is sent back to the Client with the ID token. Before even allowing the user into the client, I want to stop them because they do not have access to the app. I figure the app itself could make a call to check this OR it's possible to do in an ID or access token.

Comment: That's what I covered in the 5th paragraph - you could do it at the auth provider level - if you decide that the Client cannot get the authenticated user's ID token, you just redirect the user back to the Client with [error=access_denied](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1).